# Best way to convert ascii to characters

Tags: python, string, ascii

I have a curious problem where I am given many strings in a list. For instance, the list may be:

```
[
    "Cartier 'D&#233;claration d'un Soir'",
    "Hue Cool",
    "Lagos Caviar&#8482; Hoop"
]
```

As you can see the strings contain both normal characters as well as ascii codes. I want to convert it all to characters for a readable string.

I could go through and search for all `&#` character sets and convert from there using `;` as the delimiter. I would think this would be rather inefficient though, and I need this to be as quick as possible. I also need to keep the code very clean. Does anyone know of a better way to go about making this work? Any suggestions are appreciated!

Comment: Those are not ASCII characters.

Comment: @AlexanderGessler what are they then? I only know ascii that have that type of syntax

Comment: Those are [HTML character entities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references). In fact, you're seeing them here because they *can't* be represented in the ASCII character set (which, as a rule, covers only English text).

Comment: Awesome! Thank you for the duplicate flag. It would have taken me forever to find that they are html character entities!